Protecting a message with two private keys
I'm looking for a strategy that allows a user to encrypt a secret, which can only be decrypted by the joint effort of two independent custodians. A custodian can not unilaterally decrypt the secret.
The best I have come up with is for both custodians to have their own public/private key pair using RSA. Users encrypt their secret with both keys in a defined order. To decrypt, custodian 1 decrypts the ciphertext using their private key, and passes that message onto custodian 2. Custodian 2 then decrypts that ciphertext using their private key, returning the original secret.
The issue with this is that RSA is unable to encrypt messages exceeding the key size (minus some overhead), so it is not possible to encrypt the output of the first secret with the second RSA public key.

threshold encryption

If I have understood the question correctly.
Encryption:
Step 1: The user(eve) with the secret generates a RSA key pair and then encrypts the secret with the public key
Step 2: The user(eve) then splits the private key into two parts using Shamir's Secret Sharing and safely shares each shard with Alice and Bob
This way, neither Alice nor Bob can independently decrypt the secret with the partial key they have.
Decryption:
To decrypt the message, Alice and Bob need to agree and recombine their shards to generate the private key that can be then used to decrypt the secret.
One problem I see with this is that once Alice and Bob recombine the key they can potentially try to copy the regenerated private key, but does it really matter now that they also have access to the secret ? To overcome this problem, each time the secret is decrypted, the secret should be changed and the keys should be rotated and redistributed.

Another common issue is once Alice got the share from Bob, they do not need to send their share....

One very simple approach would be to generate two random numbers $A$ and $B$ and then define a symmetric key $C$ as $C = xor(A,B)$. $A$ and $B$ should be of appropriate key length, e.g. 128 or 256 bits. Both $A$ and $B$ are useless on their own but when brought together they create $C$ and the secret can be decrypted. This simple approach works as long as you don't have too many parties involved or when all parties are required to agree to decrypt the secret. If not everyone is required to be in on the decryption and the number of parties starts going into the double digits , then you might want to have a look at Shamir Secret Sharing which is more efficient for those scenarios.

One issue with this suggestion is that a user (separate to the custodians) needs to be able to encrypt their secret, which can then only be decrypted by the joint effort of both custodians.

@TrentGm I don't see any issue with that. The user could be the one that generates $A$, $B$ and $C$, uses $C$ to encrypt and then provides two separate custodians with $A$ and $B$. If that's not a viable solution then those details in the question were not clear enough for me to understand.

Thanks - definitely my fault for not making the requirements clear enough. Your suggestion is clever. What I didn't make clear in the original question is that the encrypted secret will be stored in an insecure location.

No worries haha, but what you clarified now doesn't really affect my answer. The secret is encrypted with strong symmetric encryption and no attacker would be able to break it, even if stored in an insecure location. Though for the encryption to be secure $A$ and $B$ need to be generated with a cryptographically secure random number generator and the user needs to keep the encryption key $C$ safe and private.

Is there any way for the keys to be provided by the custodians to each user? Ideally, each custodian will supply public keys to all users for them to encrypt their own secrets.

Why is that ideal? Encryption of large texts can get very slow and complicated with public keys. I think it's better to go with symmetric encryption in this case. You would of course need some secure way to share the keys with the custodians, public key cryptography should be used for that. Either generate the key material for $A$ and $B$ with DH or transfer them with a KEM.

You can use secret-sharing along with a PKE scheme as follows. Each custodian generates a pair of public-secret key $(pk_b, sk_b) \gets \mathsf{PKE.Setup}(1^{\lambda})$ by themselves and publish their public key. The public key of the scheme is $pk = (pk_0, pk_1)$.
To encrypt a message $m \in \{0,1\}^n$, the user randomly chooses a string $r \in \{0,1\}^n$ and sets $m' = m \oplus r$. It then encrypts $r$ and $m'$ to obtain $c_0 \gets \mathsf{PKE.Enc}(pk_0, r)$ and $c_1 \gets \mathsf{PKE.Enc}(pk_1, m')$. The ciphertext is $c = (c_0, c_1)$.
Decryption is straightforward. The first custodian will decrypt $c_0$ to obtain $r$ and send it to the second custodian, who will decrypt $c_1$ to obtain $m'$. Then, it computes $m = m' \oplus r$.
The proof of security for this scheme can be obtained from the solution given in this post.
